# How to know what obsolete methods/API's are replaced with

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I am trying to learn about sockets, the first result on Google provides some source code about resolving an IP address. When typing this code into VS2010, I see the message that it is depreciated.

I then visit the MSDN website to find out more about it, and it is indeed depreciated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The page isn't helpful in that it doesn't tell me if a different approach is suggested (ie, new or alternate namespace/methods etc).

Does any one know what the alternative is?

**EDIT**

Intellisense is not telling me:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler warning tell this?

Comment: @JeffRSon, my goodness, yes, you're right but NOT whilst writing it. If you write it out then intellisense tells you it's only depreciated. If you finish the code, then hover over it, it then tells you what to use! EG, if you type `Dns.Resolve` then no, it doesn't, but if you type `Dns.Resolve("localhost");` then yes it does.

Comment: @DaveRook: Your edit: That is not the compiler. That is intellisense. By compiling we mean pressing `ctrl-shift-B` (or choosing the menu option) to compile the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link:

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("Resolve is obsoleted for this type, please use GetHostEntry instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202")]
```

As you can see it refers to [GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When compiling you should also get a warning with the above message.

Comment: I didn't read through the syntax, I just didn't expect the answer to be in there. What a silly question from me. Thank you, this is the answer. In regards to the compiler warning, see my comments in OP - it only gives me the answer after you've written it out in full!

Comment: Yes but when compiling you must have written it out in full otherwise you'd get a compiler error. As you discovered you can also see the warning message before compiling by hovering over the method.

Comment: Yes, this is what through me off (as per my edit on my OP). It didn't give me enough. Any way, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The message that you see while compiling should contain the information that you need.

In this case, it should display `Resolve is obsoleted for this type, please use GetHostEntry instead.`

So it's telling you to use `GetHostEntry`!

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the compiler doesn't give the warning until the code is fully written (see my edit). I actually have to write something like `Dns.Resolve("");` before the compiler gives me that

Answer (score 0):

> Dns.Resolve Method
>
> .NET Framework 4.5
>
> Other Versions
>
> 1 out of 2 rated this helpful - Rate this topic
>
> Note: This API is now obsolete.
>
> Resolves a DNS host name or IP address to an IPHostEntry instance.
>
> Namespace:  System.Net  Assembly:  System (in System.dll)
>
> Syntax
>
> ---
>
> C#
>
> C++
>
> F#
>
> VB
>
> Copy
>
> **[ObsoleteAttribute("Resolve is obsoleted for this type, please use
>   GetHostEntry instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202")]**
>   public static IPHostEntry Resolve(    string hostName )
>
> Parameters hostNameType: System.String
>
> A DNS-style host name or IP address.
>
> Return Value Type: System.Net.IPHostEntry An IPHostEntry instance that
>   contains address information about the host specified in hostName.